# Почему - малина?

Tags: этимология

Почему на уголовном жаргоне (особенно в прошлом веке) воровские притоны назывались "малина"? При чем тут ягода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре русского арго читаем: 
МАЛИНА 1. Дом, квартира, жилище. 2. Притон, место сбора какой-л. компании. 3. Что-л. хорошее, вольготное, удобное. 4. Место, где много женщин. 
От *уг.* «малина» -- место, где «обрабатывается», обкрадывается жертва; место, где находятся лошади, предназначенные для кражи; соучастница воровства (обычно старуха-сводня); место, где можно спрятаться; воровской притон.

Думаю, *малина* в значении 'притон' произошло от *малина* в значении 'что-либо хорошее, вольготное' (это общеязыковое значение, во многих словарях оно зафиксировано, например, в Семантическом словаре: *Разлюли-малина, разлюли-малины* (прост.) -- о хорошем, привольном житье, времяпрепровождении). Но в этимологических словарях такой перенос значения не зафиксирован. Может, кто-нибудь найдет более точные сведения.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько версий происхождения. Все - недостаточно убедительные, поэтому за недостатком времени перечислять подробно не буду.
Но вот одну упомяну. Она связывает воровское "малина" со словом "мэлен" на иврите. Означает оно дом, квартира. В одном из значений - гостиница. 
Тут надо иметь в виду, что возникновение т.н. фени во многом связано с одесской воровской вольницей конца XIX - начала XX века, где влияние еврейского этоноса было очень сильным.

Нашел одну чудесную *[ссылку](http://booknik.ru/colonnade/facts/20-faktov-o-maline/)*. Там, кстати, и еще две версии упомянуты.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке есть тенденция иностранные слова делать как бы обрусевшими, приделывать им приставки и суффиксы, немножко менять. Мой муж вместо мерверштойер (ндс) говорит Мефистофель, тоже не по-русски, но понятнее, легче и смешнее. Наша Соседка говорила дресоли, вместо антресоли. Картофан, шузы, америкос, батник, герла, сейшн - слова моей молодости. Пётр первый привёз штоф, а мы выпиваем стопочку, берём обрусевшую бутылку с приделанным суффиксом, рюмку ( не знаю, отсюда или нет, в Голландии есть рюмер). Уверена, что много слов из идиш пришли в русский язык, тоже обрусев. Малина точно оттуда. Почему малина- потому что дресоли, так удобнее. Ну и время, и мода влияет. Когда-то Николаев звали Кокошами, теперь Колянами. Редкой Анне понравится, если ее Нюшей будут звать, а раньше нормально. Но это я уже мимо темы.