# Может ли слово обрусеть?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Вопрос возник из ответа нового участника Юлии ([Почему — малина?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)).
Дословно (вдруг ответ будет удален):

> В русском языке есть тенденция иностранные слова делать как бы обрусевшими, приделывать им приставки и суффиксы, немножко менять. Мой муж вместо мерверштойер (ндс) говорит Мефистофель, тоже не по-русски, но понятнее, легче и смешнее. Наша Соседка говорила дресоли, вместо антресоли. Картофан, шузы, америкос, батник, герла, сейшн - слова моей молодости. Пётр первый привёз штоф, а мы выпиваем стопочку, берём обрусевшую бутылку с приделанным суффиксом, рюмку ( не знаю, отсюда или нет, в Голландии есть рюмер). Уверена, что много слов из идиш пришли в русский язык, тоже обрусев...

Посмотрела в словаре значение-употребление глагола [обрусеть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C), но так и не решила — правильно ли так говорить (*обрусевшие слова*)?

Answer (score 2):

Этимологический [словарь Крылова](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy2D2.png):

> Абажу́р. Это обрусевшее слово пришло к нам из французского языка, где
> оно буквально означает «отражатель света»: abat-jour.

Таким образом, не Юлия изобретатель этого (удачного, на мой взгляд) термина. Возможно, что и не Крылов. Но его словарь (опять-таки на мой взгляд) — достаточно авторитетный источник, чтобы использовать термин *"обрусевший"* по отношению к иностранным словам, прочно вошедшим в русский язык: обросшим приставками, суффиксами, окончаниями...

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение. Да, я тоже видела это словосочетание в словаре Крылова. Но меня смутило то, что во всех других словарях (http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Obruset-19498.html) слово "обрусевший" относится только к одушевленным существительным. (Обрусевшая деревня — это *жители* деревни, которые стали русскими по языку, обычаям.) Ни одно из словарных значений я не смогла "просочетать" со словом "слово". Выходит, что слово стало русским по языку?

Comment: "Обрусевшая деревня" — это ведь метонимия; думаю, что "обрусевшее слово" тоже надо рассматривать как троп. Не знаю какой, но не буквально.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу две цитаты:

Слово **кокетка** обрусело, но prude не переведено и не вошло еще в употребление. [А. С. Пушкин. Отрывки из писем, мысли и замечания (1827)]

Почему же делать исключение для слова **пальто**, которое к тому же до того обрусело, что тоже обросло исконно русскими национальными формами: пальтишко, пальтецо и т. д. [К. И. Чуковский. Живой как жизнь (разговор о русском языке) (1962)]

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

ОБРУСЕТЬ св. Стать русским по культуре, языку, обычаям и т.п. Попал в Россию при Петре, обрусел, забыл родной язык.

Обрусить/обрусеть различаются по суффиксам: И – переходный глагол, Е –непереходный глагол (сравнить: обезлюдеть/обезлюдить). Фактически применяется только слово обрусеть (стать русским), а обрусить – это сделать русским.

Лингвистический термин

РУСИФИЦИРОВАТЬ, св. и нсв. кого. Сделать/делать русским по языку, обычаям. <Русифицироваться, страд.

Этот термин используется в лингвистике. Русификация – освоение  языком иноязычных слов (фонетическая, графическая, грамматическая).

Таким образом, можно сказать; слово русифицировалось (в лингвистике)  или обрусело (в обычной речи).

Comment: Спасибо за примеры, *Sharon*. Но мне кажется, что Пушкин имел в виду глагол "обрусить". У Даля: ОБРУСИТЬ кого, сделать русским; обруситься, обрусеть, стать, сделаться русским. Корела и мордва обрусела у нас, а жидову не скоро обрусишь. Обруселый немец. (https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) Тогда, возможно, нужно было бы так: Слово кокетка *обрусилось*, но prude не переведено... Да и пальто, похоже, обрусилось... Или я не в ту сторону думаю?

Comment: Римма, я дополнила ответ. Обрусить/обрусеть различаются по суффиксам: И – переходный глагол, Е – непереходный глагол

Comment: У Риммы сомнения по поводу одушевлённости. См. комментарии под другим ответом.

Comment: В словаре  есть примеры, где слово "обрусеть" применяется как к лицам, так и к неодушевленным предметам. Вопрос был о том, возможны ли сочетания «слово обрусело, обрусевшее слово».

Comment: Римма не нашла в словарях примеры с неодушевлёнными, кроме примера с деревней, которая представлена её жителями (одушевлённым).

Comment: Ну в Нацкорпусе посмотрите – там много обрусевших французов, англичан и пр. Надеюсь, они-то одушевленные. :)

Comment: Да нет, Римму интересует неодушевлённое. А лично у меня сомнений нет.

Comment: Они свидетельствуют о непрестанных переработках, которым подвергалось «Сказание», уже в XIII-XIV вв. значительно обрусевшее. [Н. К. Гудзий. История древней русской литературы. (XI-XV вв.) (1938)]

Comment: Что там говорить, если Римма не верит Чуковскому и даже Пушкину. Но может поверить словарям.